# NavigationView only highlighted when

Tags: java, android, view, menu, navigation

So I have created a NavigationView but when I click an item it only gets higlighted for one second and after the Sidebar is closed and the new activity is started the item is not highlighted anymore. I've searched a lot and some people seem to have similar problems but their solutions never worked for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

The issue seems to be the startActivity(). If I don't start a new activity the items get highlighted. But I still don't know how to fix it.

**Edit 2:**

I kind of found a solution but it is not very pretty. I just call `mainNavigationView.setCheckedItem(itemId);`
in every activity and so the items stay checked. Hope this helps someone because it took me way too long to find this error.

Comment: Generally, you don't start new activities from a `NavigationView` - you use Fragments and replace your view with the newly selected view.

Comment: hmm ok but then I would have all my code in one Activity right? Because I use a fragement which gets replaced with the content of the new Activity.

Comment: Right, one Activity, many Fragments

Comment: hmm okey well thank you I will keep that in mind for future projects.